# Is it advisable to have a dedicated count field in a SQL table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, graphql

I'm working in a GraphQL API that queries a PostgreSQL database. 
Two of the tables that are already created are:

- users
- users_follow

In the second table we store two foreign keys for two distinct users, which means that the first one is following the second one.

My colleague in the front end told me that would be handy for him to have a "followersCount" field in the user schema in order not to query all the followers of a user just to know how many he has.

My naive (or not) solution was to set up two triggers in the db, one increments the counter in the table user if one new follower was inserted in "users_follow" and one decrements it if one deletion happens.

Is it ok for scalability to have such a setup? Should I just "count()" to satisfy the "followersCount" in the schema?

Answer (score 3):

There is an old saying:

> Premature performance optimization is the root of all evil.

Well, I suppose the world would be a much better place if this were literally true.  But there is a grain of truth.

So, start by creating the code and trying to optimize the queries, using indexes and partitions.

Then, you can address other solutions, including triggers, materialized views, and wrapping DML operations in stored procedures (similar to triggers but easier to maintain in my opinion).

Answer (score 1):

well this should be optimal:

```
select count(user_2) as cnt from users_follow where user_1 = ?.
```

you could wrap it as a callable function `get_user_follower_count( x )` to make it easy on the other guy.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I already considered this but I thought that perhaps would be overkill to make this query all the time instead of querying one row in users which should be a much faster one.

Comment: Test if you really need to store redundant information and accept the overhead of a trigger for a small speedup. First try like this answer suggests, and only if you find out that the performance isn't good enough, consider using a trigger.